# Split a file into mutiple files based on specific pattern

Tags: bash, unix

I have an input file like this:

**Input.txt:**

```
*******************************************************************
**
**
**
**
**  report ID: COBX COLLIATERAL IN MARGINX MEMO REPORT
**
**
**
***********************************************************************
ehwq
A
s
fdf
fg
gfdg
fgfd

*******************************************************************
**
**
**
**
**  REPORT ID : CZXC COLLATREAL ACTVTY BY CRD
**
**
**
***********************************************************************
ain lik
fklhsdk
dgfjkdghdfkj
dgfdjhgkjdf
fgjhfkjdghfkjd
fg
jdfkhgkjdfh
```

When I run the script, the output should be split into multiple files, like this:

**file 1:**

```
*******************************************************************
**
**
**
**
**  report ID: COBX COLLIATERAL IN MARGINX MEMO REPORT
**
**
**
***********************************************************************
ehwq
A
s
fdf
fg
gfdg
fgfd
```

**file 2:**

```
*******************************************************************
**
**
**
**
**  REPORT ID : CZXC COLLATREAL ACTVTY BY CRD
**
**
**
***********************************************************************
ain lik
fklhsdk
dgfjkdghdfkj
dgfdjhgkjdf
fgjhfkjdghfkjd
fgjdfkhgkjdfh
```

What I have tried:

```
grep -i "report id" $1 > ./pattern.txt j=head -1 pattern.txt;
echo "first line is : - $j";
count=0;
name="output";
sed -n '2,$p' pattern.txt > pattern_1.txt while read i do count=expr $count + 1;
line=echo "$i";
echo "line is --- $i -- end";
sed -n '/'"$j"'/,/'"$line"'/ {/'"$line"'/d;p;}' $1 > ${name}_${count}.txt;
j=`echo "$line";
sed -i '1i\ ************************************************************‌​*******\ **\ **\ **\ ** ' ${name}_${count}.txt;
done < pattern_1.txt last_pattern=tail -1 pattern.txt`;
sed -n '/'"$last_pattern"'/,$ {p;}' $1 > ${name}_last.txt;
sed -i '1i\ ************************************************************‌​*******\ **\ **\ **\ ** ' ${name}_last.txt;
```

Comment: What have you done till now? Can you show us the code?

Comment: What is your question?¿

Comment: This would be an easy job for `csplit`...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to go, but I am assuming there will be an empty line in your file after each block, as in the example you posted :

```
i=0;
while read line
do
     printf "$line\n" >> splitted_part_${i}.txt
     if [ $( echo "$line" | grep -e "^[ ]*$" | wc -l ) -gt 0 ] 
     then 
           (( i++ ))
     fi
done <<< "$( cat input.txt )"
```

I create a new file every time a new EMPTY line is encountered.
In your example lines 18 and 36 are empty :

```
bash-4.1$ grep -n -e "^[ ]*$" input.txt
18:
36:
```

Hope this works for you. Let me know.